# HOC vs Wrapper in render function

Tags: reactjs

Is there any difference between these two approaches except "code organizing"?

I have bunch of custom input elemts, like TextInput, NumberInput, etc.

I use them directly

```
const TextInput = (props) => <input type="text" {...props} />

const App = (mainProps) => <div>
  <TextInput {...props} errors={['error text']} />
</div>
```

and I have FormInput component that encapsulates error messages rendering for any input component.

```
const FormInput = (props) => <div>
  // Render input here
  <span>{props.errors.join(', ')}</span>
</div>
```

I see two different implementation 
1) HOC

```
const FormInputHOC = (C) => {
  const FormInput = (props) => <div>
    <C {...props} />
    <span>{props.errors.join(', ')}</span>
  </div>
}

export default FormInputHOC(TextInput)
```

2) Wrapper

```
const FormInput = (props) => <div>
  {props.children}
  <span>{props.errors.join(', ')}</span>
</div>

const TextInput = (props) => <FormInput errors={props.errors}>
  <input type="text" {...props} />
</FormInput>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, there is no real differences, but when you want to do operations on the component state, HOC allows you to code function that can work on `this.state`. This state will be the one of the component wrapped by the HOC.

Example:

With HOC, you can code a `componentWillReceiveProps()` function that will add or remove some data on the component state each time a component receive props. And you can use this HOC on a several components.